# Dynamically add button to the mat-table angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, angular10

How can I add action column  with edit and delete button dynamically. I have the below setup

**Data source in the parent component**

```
columns: MatTable[] = [
    { columnDef: 'position', header: 'No.', cell: (element: any) => `${element.position}` },
    { columnDef: 'name', header: 'Name', cell: (element: any) => `${element.name}` },
    { columnDef: 'weight', header: 'Weight', cell: (element: any) => `${element.weight}` },
    { columnDef: 'symbol', header: 'Symbol', cell: (element: any) => `${element.symbol}` },
    { columnDef: 'action', header: 'action', cell: (element: any) => `${element.action}` }
  ];

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H', action:`<a mat-raised-button href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>` },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne', action:`<a (click)="openDialog('Update',element)">Edit</a> | <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',element)">Delete</a>` },
];

 dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.matTableConfig.columns = this.columns;
    this.matTableConfig.filter = false;
    this.matTableConfig.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
```

In the child component

```
 @Input() matTableConfig: MatTableConfig;

 <table mat-table [dataSource]="matTableConfig?.dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let column of matTableConfig?.columns" matColumnDef={{column.columnDef}}>
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{ column.header }} </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ column.cell(element) }} </td>
            </ng-container>
    
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    
            <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
            <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                <td class="mat-cell" colspan="columns.length">No data matching the filter</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: what you need about dynamically row action? when delete btn is appear?

Comment: Because the table column are dynamic, I can't hard code the column. If so how I don't know the below answer will not going to work.

Comment: you can push `delete` column in columns after get data from api.

Comment: I got your point, but what about the content on the column, can you please show an example

Comment: could my answer help you?

Comment: Not really the way I want, but it is near to that, I need to add delete and edit button dynamically. In some of the rows, there will be only one button (DELETE) in another row there might be two button (EDIT | DELETE) and the some of the rows there will be (EDIT) button

Comment: so you need a field for detect what row is editable. you can disable it but it need to exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you explained to me in the comments, i provide an stackblitz example.

see [there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dyn-columns?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-text-column-advanced-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: right;">{{tr[82].a}}</th>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: right;">
 <button mat-icon-button (click)="delProd(element)" [matTooltip]="tr[82].a + ' ' + element.id">
 <mat-icon style="color: crimson">delete</mat-icon>
 </button>
 </td>
</ng-container>
```